# Pydoop mapreduce "AttributeError: module 'wordcount_minimal' has no attribute '__main__'"

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hortonworks-data-platform

I installed `Pydoop` and am trying to run `MapReduce` jobs. Just to do a dry run, I tried executing the word count examples `wordcount_minimal.py` and `wordcount_full.py`. Both of them hang at the map phase. In the end of the `stderr`, I find this message as per the script I run:

> module 'wordcount_minimal' has no attribute '**main**'

or

> module 'wordcount_full' has no attribute '**main**'

I executed the job using the command:

> pydoop submit --upload-file-to-cache wordcount_full.py wordcount_full *hdfs_input_dir* *hdfs_output_dir*

Unable to find the reason behind this. Any idea what could be the reason?

I was able to execute the example from the [`pydoop script`](https://crs4.github.io/pydoop/tutorial/pydoop_script.html) using the `map` and `reduce` functions and it completed successfully. But with the `pydoop submit` option, I have this issue. Not sure if I am missing something.

PS: I have a cluster with 2 nodes running `Hortonworks HDP 2.6.5`. `Pydoop` is installed on both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, pydoop submit expects an entry point called `__main__`, but you can modify this via `--entry-point`. For instance, if your code is:

```
class Mapper ...
class Reducer ...
def run():
    pipes.run_task(pipes.Factory(Mapper, Reducer))
```

You can run it via `pydoop submit --entry-point run ...`

Comment: Thank you. I used this method and specified the entry-point to main and it worked. However, I am still confused as to the use of `if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()` in the script. I thought it was supposed to pick this one by default.